# Проверка сертификата сервера клиентом

Tags: javascript, ajax

Отправляю AJAX запрос со своего сайта на API транспортной компании ПЭК и в ответ получаю статус 0. Перепробовал все возможные варианты.

Прочитал на их сайте: "Запрос должен осуществляться по протоколу HTTPS с обязательной проверкой сертификата сервера клиентом".

Возможно дело в проверке сертификата, как это организовать на JS ?

Мой код:

```js
let urlCoords = `https://kabinet.pecom.ru/api/v1/branches/findzonebycoordinates/`,
    key = "some api key",
    log = "mylogin";    
   
let data = {
    "latitude": +localStorage.GEOLatitude,
    "longitude": +localStorage.GEOLongitude
               },
    sendData = JSON.stringify(data),
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      
req.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(req.readyState != 4 || req.status != 200)
 console.log(req.readyState, req.status)      
    console.log(req.response)
   //let response = JSON.parse(req.response);
     }      
req.open("POST", urlCoords, true, log, key);      
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");      
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.send(sendData);
```

Comment: А вы ошибки в консоли смотрели?

Comment: Ошибок нет. Вывел в консоль readyState и status: 

readyState = 1, status = 0 
<empty string>
readyState = 4, status = 0
<empty string>

Comment: Аутентификация осуществляется c помощью Basic-аутентификации, в качестве логина необходимо использовать имя пользователя личного кабинета клиента «ПЭК», в качестве пароля — любой из активных ключей доступа.

Comment: Попробуйте: `req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64.encode(log + ":" + key));`

Comment: Получаю base64 is not defined, если использовать `req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(log + ":" + key));` тогда возникается ошибка CORS